# how to detect client commit activity in a SOLR cluster

Tags: solr

all

i am trying to find the number of client commits in a SOLR cluster (as opposed to autocommits).

looking thru statistics available from a solr server via /solr/admin/metrics, there appear to be 3 main commit statistics:

UPDATE.updateHandler.softAutoCommits

UPDATE.updateHandler.commits

UPDATE.updateHandler.autoCommits

If i execute the following calculation: (commits - autoCommits - softAutoCommits)

would this give me the number of client-issued commits?

thnx v much for your time on this, mr